# Is it possible to have colorized diffs for Mercurial notifications?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-extension

We're in the process of migrating from Subversion to Mercurial.  The VisualSVN server we were using produced colored diffs within its notification emails, but I can't find how to reproduce this in Mercurial.  I have enabled the `color` extension on the server, but this has no effect on the emails produced.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does send the emails?

Comment: The Notification hook is set up on a central server, and (I presume) the emails are sent from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are sent by a standard hook, which on my Debian system is in `/usr/share/pyshared/hgext/notify.py`. It doesn't contain any code to send coloured mail. You could either take a copy and modify it to do colouring, or write a new hook. That could be a shell script using:

```
hg diff --color=always
```

or you could use the [Mercurial Python API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The lack of 'built-in' support for colored, HTML emails makes HG feel like a step backwards from SVN (or VisualSVN, at least), but fortunately it's not a deal breaker.